# Is there a way to force a multi-word li in a horizontal nav menu to stay on one line?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I've got some HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Menu Item One</li>
        <li>Menu Item Two</li>
        <li>Menu Item Three</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is styled as a horizontal menu.  The number of links in my list are such that the nav needs to drop down to two lines.  But I don't want it to drop at a place mid-li.  Which is to say that because my links are multi-word, it tends to drop in the middle of an item.  Any way to do this that forces the next line to always be at a place in-between the `<li>` elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just add the css `white-space:nowrap;` to the li's

Comment: I don't think there is a word-wrap: none;

It looks like just "normal" and "break-word", neither of which are any help here.  https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap

Comment: @binaryorganic: He said `white-space: nowrap;`, not `word-wrap: none` (though I don't think `white-space: nowrap;` is the answer to your problem).

Comment: @thirtydot - yes, `white-space: nowrap;` solves the problem.  It only said `word-wrap: none;` for about 10 seconds before i realized i had used the wrong settings.  See http://jsfiddle.net/Uhcbm/ and shrink the right pane until it causes each li to wrap as a whole.

Comment: @binaryorganic - it only said said `word-wrap: none;` for about 10 seconds, i changed it right away.  You just didn't refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Persumably you could try replacing the spaces in your li-items with non-breaking-spaces, like so:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Menu&nbsp;Item&nbsp;One</li>
        <li>Menu&nbsp;Item&nbsp;Two</li>
        <li>Menu&nbsp;Item&nbsp;Three</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav li {display:block; float:left; white-space:pre;}
```

See the interface here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3h9Kw/